# What is wrong with my Yup validation scheme?

Tags: javascript, formik, yup

I'm building a simple form using Formik and Yup.

There are two dropdowns and two inputs. Model, unfortunately, must be nested the following way:

```
securityQuestions: {
    questions: {
        0: '',
        1: ''
    },
    answers: {
        0: '',
        1: ''
    }
}
```

I'm doing something like this (not really, it's a bit more complicated in the real code, I have to build a scheme dynamically from the config I get from the backend, but the result (the scheme) is exactly the same (I've checked) as if I'd done this that simple:

```
const schema = yup
  .object()
  .shape({
    securityQuestions: yup.object().shape({
      questions: yup.object().shape({
        0: yup.string().required(),
        1: yup.string().required()
      }),
      answers: yup.object().shape({
        0: yup.string().required(),
        1: yup.string().required()
      })
    })
  });
```

Inputs names in Formik are `securityQuestions.questions[0], securityQuestions.answers[0]` and so on. Formik works.

[image]

However, when trying to submit a form, I get this:

```
securityQuestions.answers must be a `object` type, but the final value was: `null` (cast from the value `[\n  \"undefined\",\n  \"undefined\"\n]`).\n If \"null\" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as `.nullable()`"
```

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: It means your yup's validation schema expecting an obj but receiving a null value. It might because the  ```securityQuestions.answers``` are not being set correctly, or being set to null.

Comment: I don't expect securityQuestions.answers to have value at all, it's an array (or object) to contain properties to be mapped to Formik

Comment: If so, given with the limited code, you could use the [Arrays and Nested Objects](https://formik.org/docs/guides/arrays) or [FieldArray](https://formik.org/docs/api/fieldarray) to handle the form.

Comment: I thought this was what I was actually doing, Formik works just fine, the problem is with Yup

Comment: How about adding ```.nullable()``` in the answers by ```answers: yup.object().shape({ 0: yup.string().required(), 1: yup.string().required() }).nullable()``` ?

Comment: Then it's not validating anything in the form at all

Comment: How about using yup ```mixed()```? which can handle any type of value? So the code will looks like ```answers: yup.mixed().shape({0: yup.string().required(),1: yup.string().required() })```